# How to compare two lists with multiple objects and set values?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists. Each list has a `Name` object and and a `Value` object. I want to loop through `list1` and check if each `list1 Name` object is the same as the `list2 Name` object (the linq code below does this).

If they match, then I want the `List1 Value` to be set with the `list2 Value` How can this be done?

```
list1              list2
Name    Value      Name    Value
john    apple      John    orange
peter   null       Peter   grape
```

I need it to look like this:

```
list1              list2
Name    Value      Name    Value
john    orange     john    orange
peter   grape      peter   grape
```

Linq code:

```
var x = list1.Where(n => list2.Select(n1 => n1.Name).Contains(n.Name));
```

Comment: the regular expression match requirement is gone?

Comment: @IgorPashchuk: He removed it after nobody answered it. I added a comment to the accepted answer just before he removed it, but I think I was too late for him to notice.

Comment: @IgorPashchuk I removed it because I need to reword the question. I can put it back up in a couple of minutes

Comment: @IgorPashchuk I have the question reworded here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535414/how-to-do-a-string-replace-in-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filtering you can use `LINQ`, to set the values use a loop:

```
var commonItems = from x in list1
                  join y in list2
                  on x.Name equals y.Name
                  select new { Item = x, NewValue = y.Value };

foreach(var x in commonItems)
{
     x.Item.Value = x.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: `select { Item = x, NewValue = y.Value };` line does not work. `x` and `y` can't be found

Comment: you are missing `new` after `select`

Comment: @BenScotch: You could add a `where` clause to the first part of the linq query `from x in list1.Where(item => regex.IsMatch(item.Value)) join y in list2 ...` You would just have to set up the regex before the query and run the foreach at the end (how it is in this answer already). (I see you have now removed the regex part of your question and also the comment from this answer, but I'll leave this comment in case you still find it helpful).

Comment: @JasonDown I have the question reworded here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535414/how-to-do-a-string-replace-in-linq)

Answer (score 1):

In one result, you can get the objects joined together:

```
var output= from l1 in list1
        join l2 in list2
        on l1.Name equals l2.Name
        select new { List1 = l1, List2 = l2};
```

And then manipulate the objects on the returned results. by looping through each and setting:

```
foreach (var result in output)
  result.List1.Value = result.List2.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a left join

```
var x = from l1 in list1
        join l2 in list2 on l1.Name equals l2.Name into l3
        from l2 in l3.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { Name = l1.Name, Value = (l2 == null ? l1.Value : l2.Value) };
```