# How to do a String.Replace in LINQ?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, list

Here is what I am trying to do but with no success. I want to call `from x in list1` and `join y in list2 where regex.Match(x.Value).Success`. After these steps I need to call `String.Replace` twice on `x.Value`. Then call the `on` and `select` operators. I want it to look something like the second example. How can this be acheived?

Here is how my lists look like:

```
list1              list2
Name    Value      Name    Value
item.1  $(prod1)   prod1   prodVal1
item.2  $(prod2)   prod2   prodVal2
item.3  prod3      prod3   prodVal3
```

Here is how my lists should look like:

```
updatedList         
Name    Value     
item.1  prodVal1   
item.2  prodVal2       
item.3  prod3
```

Example 1 (This is what I currently have):

```
foreach (var x in list1)
{
    Match match = reg.Match(x.Value);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        x.Value = x.Value.Replace("$(", "");
        x.Value = x.Value.Replace(")", "");
    }
}

var commonItems = from x in list1
                  join y in list2
                  on x.Value equals y.Name
                  //where regex.Match(x.Value).Success
                  select new { Item = x, NewValue = y.Value };

foreach (var x in commonItems)
{
    x.Item.Value = x.NewValue;
}
```

Example 2:

```
var commonItems = from x in list1
                  join y in list2
                  where regex.Match(x.Value).Success
                  //do x.Value.Replace("$(", "")
                  //do x.Value.Replace(")", "")
                  //then call
                  on x.Value equals y.Name
                  select new { Item = x, NewValue = y.Value };

foreach (var x in commonItems)
{
    x.Item.Value = x.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: in the select do you want to return the original value or the value after the string.replace?

Comment: shouldn't you get a single list in the end? the commonItems list. in your example you have 2 lists...

Comment: can you really have NULL values in list1? it's going to complicate the query

Comment: @Vland I changed it, to not have a null.

Comment: why is item.3 getting prod2 as value in the updatedList?

Comment: I mean, shouldn't it be **item.3  prodVal3** ?

Comment: @Vland I changed it, but the value doesn't get updated, because of the `where` clause that has the `regex.match`. the regex pattern looks for items that have `$(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you need `Regex.Match`? you could obtain the same result without using it, anyway I added both versions...

In the 1° version you can use a simple If statement to check if the value was changed

```
NewValue = x.Value != x1 ? y.Value: x.Value
```

**Sample code**

given this class

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

.

adding items

```
        var list1 = new List<MyClass>();
        list1.Add(new MyClass { Name = "item.1", Value = "$(prod1)" } );
        list1.Add(new MyClass { Name = "item.2", Value = "$(prod2)" });
        list1.Add(new MyClass { Name = "item.3", Value = "prod3" });

        var list2 = new List<MyClass>();
        list2.Add(new MyClass { Name = "prod1", Value = "prodVal1" });
        list2.Add(new MyClass { Name = "prod2", Value = "prodVal2" });
        list2.Add(new MyClass { Name = "prod3", Value = "prodVal3" });
```

getting common list

```
        var q =  from x in list1
                 let x1 = x.Value.Replace("$(", "").Replace(")", "")
                join y in list2 on x1 equals y.Name
                select new { 
                    Item = x.Name, 
                    NewValue = x.Value != x1 ? y.Value: x.Value 
                };


        foreach (var s in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Item + " " + s.NewValue);
        }
```

result

```
item.1 prodVal1
item.2 prodVal2
item.3 prod3
```

---

**PS**: I don't think you need `Regex`, but just in case this version will work using it.

```
var q = from x in list1
        let x1 = x.Value.Replace("$(", "").Replace(")", "")
        join y in list2 on x1 equals y.Name
        select new
        {
            Item = x.Name,
            NewValue = Regex.Match(x.Value, x1).Success ? x.Value : y.Value
        };
```

Comment: regex.match is needed because i only need to do the replacement on the  objects that match.

Comment: @BenScotch I handled that adding the IF in the select statement. try it, item.3 is not getting its value replaced

Comment: @BenScotch added also the Regex version to it, just check the .Success value in the select statement so you know if you need to change the value or not

Comment: the reason why i need the regex, so that i can check the which values i need to do the replacements on, otherwise, there are more replacements than there should be. You definitely deserve the accepted answer!

Comment: @BenScotch I understand your need Ben, this is why in both version we check if `x1` (the replaced string) is equal to `x.value`. so we know **when** we should take the new value and **when** we should stick with the old one. `Regex` is usually needed for much more complicated pattern search than a simple string equality check. anyway thanks for the vote and good luck :)

Answer (score 8):

If I understood correctly what you want is to use **`let`** in your query:

```
var commonItems = from x in list1
                  join y in list2
                  let newX = x.Value.Replace("$(", "").Replace(")", "")
                  where regex.Match(x.Value).Success
                 &&  newX == y.Name
                  select new { Item = newX, NewValue = y.Value };
```

Comment: where needs to be before the let, and I get this error: `Expected contextual keyword 'on'`

Comment: @BenScotch Check the documentation on let [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx)